# how to create php file and load it in wordpress post?

Tags: functions

I need to create php file like **download.php**.

In this file download links for movie or program,

when users click on download button, this file **download.php** load in  fancybox and display download links.

http://sitename/template_path/download.php?post_id=post_id

Comment: Whats the question? You have simply made a statement that you want to create this type of page.. confused>

Sorry, just re-read your TITLE, How to!>> good starting point here. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/

Comment: You did not understand my question & my english is not good.

Answer (score 0):

It is not normal practice in WP development to include executable PHP in content.

Most typically this would be implemented with a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) which provides safe element to put into content, which renders a more complicated output required.

Not sure about `download.php` part, I would guess that might be better off incorporated into WP runtime as well, but depends on what exactly it does and how.

Answer (score 0):

This post same my id [Looking for a better way to handle an ajax script that pulls in post data on click](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225792/looking-for-a-better-way-to-handle-an-ajax-script-that-pulls-in-post-data-on-cli)

but i need to load current post metabox data in custom php file.

Answer (score 0):

Executing the PHP file in the templates is not recommended, following are the suggestions:

- Make a shortcode for the PHP file to execute in functions.php and
  then use the shortcode in content editor.
- Use the Bootstrap Modal which is a pure html code which you can code it in the content editor directly. example: [Bootstrap Modal](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)